# What is the maximum sound level

Tags: c#, audio

I am creating a small alarm that will have to set the speaker volume to the maximum before starting the alarm. Every thing is working but I don't know what the maximum value for the speakers is. Does someone of you know it or know where I can find it?

Here is how I set the volume of the speakers:

```
defaultDevice.AudioEndpointVolume.MasterVolumeLevel = 1;
```

BR

Comment: I'm guessing the max will be 100?

Comment: This has nothing to do with WPF or .net-4.0 so I removed those tags.  What audio library are you using?

Comment: Should be 11. That way if someone has it all the way up at 10 but wants it a bit louder, they can turn it up to 11. /spinal Tap.

Comment: It works on the test computers when I set it to 1 but when I try to set it to 3 it crashes on some of the computers with the message that the value is out of range. That is why I want to find the maximum level for each computer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your hint I found the answer. The correct answer for my problem is:

```
defaultDevice.AudioEndpointVolume.MasterVolumeLevel = defaultDevice.AudioEndpointVolume.VolumeRange.MaxdB;
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [IAudioEndpointVolume::GetVolumeRange API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368039%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It will give you the range of volume in decibels.

Comment: Hey I have this two audio devices `private readonly MMDeviceEnumerator devEnum = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
        private readonly MMDevice defaultDevice;` but I can't find the getVolumeRange - only a VolumeRange which I don't know how to use. Can you give me an example og useage?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the [IAudioEndpointVolume](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370892%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface, it has a GetVolumeRange method that gets the volume range in decibels.

Comment: Hey I have this two audio devices `private readonly MMDeviceEnumerator devEnum = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
        private readonly MMDevice defaultDevice;` but I can't find the getVolumeRange - only a VolumeRange which I don't know how to use. Can you give me an example og useage?

Comment: What you're seeing is the difference between C++ and C#. The online documentation is for C++, which does not have have properties so uses Get and Set prefixes. In C# the same methods become properties, so the Get/Set prefix is hidden from you.